# Java how to call kotlin extension method

Tags: java, android, kotlin-android-extensions

I use kotlin write a extension method

```
package com.zhongan.zachat.extention

import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast

/**
 * Created by Carl on 2016/12/1.
 *
*
*/


fun Context.toastLong(msg:String) = Toast.makeText(this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

fun Context.toastshort(msg:String) = Toast.makeText(this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

when I in `kotlin activity` call `toastLong("test")`
is ok.
but In `java actvity`  IDE say can not found this method.

how Can I call kotlin extension method in java code

Comment: How are you trying to call it?

Comment: @user254948 just like  `this.toastLong("test");`

Answer (score 8):

Based on [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

> Extensions do not actually modify classes they extend.

It should be noted that the extension can not be called from the object class, since the original class is still the same. (So Context does not magically have a extra function, hence it can't be called using Context.functionName in Java)

You should be able to call it using:

```
com.zhongan.zachat.extention.<fileName>.toastLong(ctx,"string")
```

e.g. if the file is called kotlinFile.kt:

```
com.zhongan.zachat.extention.KotlinFileKt.toastLong(ctx,"string")
```

Comment: You can manually import it though, you don't need the full package name.